# Accessing global variable in python class __init__

Tags: python, global-variables, kivy

I am having an issue with accessing a globally declared variable in two separate classes. This is a kivy application that uses pandas for backend support.

Here is the initialization of the global variable, `raw_data`, and where it is originally modified (in the `show_raw_data` func):

```
# original dataframe
raw_data = None

class IntroScreen(Screen):

    def __init__ (self, **kwargs):
        super (IntroScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.preview_screen_layout.add_widget(Button(text="View Raw Data", on_release=self.goto_raw_data))

    # switch to preview screen and show raw data when import is clicked
    def show_raw_data(self, *args):
        global file_path_list
        global raw_data
        try:

            # check input is correct
            if ".xlsx" in file_path_list["orig_data"]:
                raise ValueError
            else:
                # open csv file to display and display it
                raw_data = pd.read_csv(file_path_list["orig_data"])
                dfgui.show(raw_data)

                # move to next screen
                self.manager.current = 'preview_screen'
```

And here is where I am trying to access to be able to display the data that was read in using pandas:

```
class PreviewScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super (PreviewScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        global raw_data
        dfgui.show(raw_data)

    # display raw data to user 
    def goto_raw_data(self, *args):
        global raw_data
        dfgui.show(raw_data)
```

But here is my problem - in the PreviewScreen class, accessing the `global raw_data` within `goto_raw_data` works perfectly fine and `raw_data` contains the pandas dataframe, but when accessing the same global variable in the `__init__`, it is still initialized to `None` as it is in the original declaration.

Is there something strange going on in my init function that is preventing the global variable from populating? I was thinking maybe the order in which the compiler reads the classes, but other than that I can't think of anything.

Is there a way around this so that I can access the global variable in the `__init__` or am I stuck to accessing in a defined function.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: "Sorry about the indentation errors, I couldn't figure out how to format correctly." - copy-paste your code into the question, then highlight everything you pasted (both the parts that appear code-formatted in the preview and the parts that don't) and hit Ctrl-K, or the button with the braces on it.

Comment: To make it easier to help you, you should provide an [mcve]. Having to read lots and lots of pages of code is most likely scaring away people trying to help.

Comment: If `raw_data` is still `None` in `__init__`, then the code that was supposed to set it to something else probably hasn't actually happened yet. You can't use results before you compute them.

Comment: @user2357112 : thank you for that, fixed indents. And yes I know the problem is that the setting of 'raw_data' hasn't happened yet, but I am wondering why it has happened when using a defined method, and not in the __inti__() method

Comment: @ChristianKönig : thank you for the heads up, also fixed as much as possible

Comment: Are these classes in different modules? If you're trying to share a global variable between modules, don't do that. `from` imports actually create new variables, and mutable global state is bad enough when it's confined to a single module.

Comment: No they are in the same module. I guess my question is, why has the event of the global variable being modified happened in one method and not __init__

Answer (score 1):

Too much code to go through, however, i can somewhat replicate what you are trying to do it and it works

```
raw_data = None

class IntroScreen:

 def change_raw_data_value(self):
    global raw_data
    raw_data = 'Changed raw_data once'

 def print_raw_data(self):
    print(raw_data)


class PreviewScreen:

 def __init__(self):
    global raw_data
    print(raw_data)

 def change_raw_data_value(self):
    global raw_data
    raw_data = 'Changed raw_data twice' 

 def print_raw_data(self):
    print(raw_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
 intro_screen = IntroScreen()
 intro_screen.change_raw_data_value()
 intro_screen.print_raw_data()

 preview_screen = PreviewScreen()
 preview_screen.change_raw_data_value()
 preview_screen.print_raw_data()

Changed raw_data once
Changed raw_data once -> from Preview Screen __init__
Changed raw_data twice
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

Comment: Thank you for this, and I have since shortened the code. This is what I am after, but can't seem to get it to work as yours does. Thank you for the help!

Comment: It's a lot clear now with the short code. I'm assuming the else condition is executed inside the show_raw_data from IntroScreen class prior to the initialization of Preview Screen. Is it how your code flows?

Comment: I think have I have tracked down the problem to the fact that PreviewScreen is instantiated before the click event that occurs in IntroScreen, hence why raw_data is not initialized yet. The way Kivy works, the screens are initialized in the very beginning, and click events on the layout happen post-initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here. There isn't a solution to fix it because it is the way the program is setup. The screens are initialized as so:

```
class OutlierDetectionApp(App):

        def build(self):
            # set window size and color
            #Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)

            # initialize screen manager and create screens
            my_screenmanager = ScreenManager()
            intro_screen = IntroScreen(name='intro_screen')
            preview_screen = PreviewScreen(name='preview_screen')

            # add screens to screen manager
            my_screenmanager.add_widget(intro_screen)
            my_screenmanager.add_widget(preview_screen)
            return my_screenmanager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    OutlierDetectionApp().run()
```

Therefore, the `PreviewScreen` is being initialized before the button clicks that set the `raw_data` to an actual file, so the data is `None` still at the time of screen initialization. The reason that it works in a self defined method is because the logic of these methods (ie: `goto_raw_data`) is evaluated at runtime, in which case `raw_data` would be correctly populated.

Thanks for all those who put in thoughts to allow me to come to this conclusion! Time to reformat the code a little bit to work around this issue.